# Element-wise rbind lists of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I have a list of 3 lists, each with an equal number of dataframes, 32, to be precise, and I wish to `rbind`  them across the lists element-wise. To give a simpler example, suppose you have one list with 2 lists, each with 2 dataframes, like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  x  y
1 a 11
2 b 12
3 c 13

[[1]][[2]]
  x  y
1 a 14
2 b 15
3 c 16


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  x  y
1 a 17
2 b 18
3 c 19

[[2]][[2]]
  x  y
1 a 21
2 b 22
3 c 23
```

given by:

```
A <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(11,12,13))
colnames(A)<-c("x","y")
B <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(14,15,16))
colnames(B)<-c("x","y")
C <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(17,18,19))
colnames(C)<-c("x","y")
D <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(21,21,23))
colnames(D)<-c("x","y")
L1 <- list(A,B)
L2 <- list(C,D)
L <- list(L1,L2)
```

How can I `rbind` the dataframes across the 2 lists element-wise, such that the final `output` is:

```
[[1]]
  x  y
1 a 11
2 b 12
3 c 13
4 a 17
5 b 18
6 c 19

[[2]]
  x  y
1 a 14
2 b 15
3 c 16
4 a 21
5 b 21
6 c 23
```

In this example, I could just `output <- list(rbind(A,C),rbind(B,D))`

But I want to do it for a much larger list of lists of dataframes

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide us with the code to yield the example datasets you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for the code to construct the data, but `dput` is to be preferred, as sometimes there are attributes or similar things, that you might not be aware of, but they might be vital, and `dput` embeds those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could just use `transpose` from `purrr`:

```r
output <- lapply(purrr::transpose(L), 
                 function(l) do.call(rbind, args = l))
output
```

Comment: I would avoid making claims like "Fastest" unless you know that it is.  According to `microbenchmark`, the three different answers (at the time of this posting) are not interestingly different from each other in terms of timing. In terms of average time over 1000 runs, the `purrr::transpose()` method is actually slowest, though not statistically different from the other methods.

Comment: I totally meant fastest "to write". Sorry, will edit this..

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! And it did answer the question. I should stress that most of other answers present only a solution to the simpler minimum reproducible example given by me imitating my own solution for the example given. They do not answer the question for large lists of large lists of dataframes. This one should be voted up.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
A <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(11,12,13))
colnames(A)<-c("x","y")
B <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(14,15,16))
colnames(B)<-c("x","y")
C <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(17,18,19))
colnames(C)<-c("x","y")
D <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"), c(21,21,23))
colnames(D)<-c("x","y")
L1 <- list(A,B)
L2 <- list(C,D)
L <- list(L1,L2)
lapply(1:2, \(i)rbind(L1[[i]], L2[[i]]))
#> [[1]]
#>   x  y
#> 1 a 11
#> 2 b 12
#> 3 c 13
#> 4 a 17
#> 5 b 18
#> 6 c 19
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   x  y
#> 1 a 14
#> 2 b 15
#> 3 c 16
#> 4 a 21
#> 5 b 21
#> 6 c 23
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map2` like this:

```
library(purrr)
map2(L1,L2,rbind)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  x  y
1 a 11
2 b 12
3 c 13
4 a 17
5 b 18
6 c 19

[[2]]
  x  y
1 a 14
2 b 15
3 c 16
4 a 21
5 b 21
6 c 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
Map(rbind, L1, L2)
```

```
[[1]]
  x  y
1 a 11
2 b 12
3 c 13
4 a 17
5 b 18
6 c 19

[[2]]
  x  y
1 a 14
2 b 15
3 c 16
4 a 21
5 b 21
6 c 23
```